# Outbound Map not being used

Tags: biztalk

I have a receive port. It calls a stored procedure for transport, then the receive pipeline is just passthrureceive (I tried XMLReceive, but that caused many more issues). I have a send port that has the filter set so it picks up the type of the receive port. The send port has a map and send pipeline. The map maps the xml from the receive port to a flat file schema, and then sends it to it's location. THe send pipeline has a flat file assembler.

So the map never runs. I just get errors from the send pipeline saying it can't match the document. No it can't, because it wasn't mapped. I read that you need an XML Disassembler on the recieve pipeline of the receive location. I added that, and that just started destroying my messages. They just get turned into a blank message or just a " in the message. So the XML disassembler is clearly not working right. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I have to use the XML disassembler to make the map run. The reason it was erasing my messages is, well I don't know the reason, but when I set the schema to "elementFormDefault = Qualified", it worked. I'm not really sure what that did, as I really don't have a good understanding of the whole qualified message thing, but that was the problem for me.

Comment: [elementFormDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256460) on `xs:sxhema` and `form` on `xs:element` on an xsd defines whether local ('inner') elements need to be prefixed with the target namespace or not. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#NS) for an example of the difference.

Comment: Well it seems to me that, yes they always should. How would it work without it. Why is this not the default?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wizard in Visual Studio to help you create the schemas and bindings that you use to communicate with stored procedures. I guess you didn't use that?  (Right click on the project, hit "Add", then "Add Generated Items", then "Consume Adapter Service")

I'm calling my stored procedure from an orchestration hooked to two way send/receive port. I'm using a custom WCF type port with XMLTransmit and XMLReceive for the pipelines. This seems to work fine. The caveat being it's always a bit fiddly getting WCF to work since there are so many options.

Comment: I am a very basic Biztalk user and none of that really meant anything to me, lol. Sorry. I'll vote it up, it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to map from one format to another on ports, you need to have MessageType promoted. In your case it can be accomplished by using XMLReceive on the receive pipeline.